# Two vertical divs, each with auto scroll with max-height

Tags: html, css, autoscroll

I would like to achieve the following requirements. Let's say I have two containers (top and bottom) inside a main container:

1) Both top and bottom containers need to be scrollable only when content overflows in each container

2) Top container needs to have max height capped at 50% as content grows

3) Bottom container's max height really depends on the height of the top container. 
For example, if the top container contains 30% height, the bottom container be scrollable when its height becomes larger than 70%.

I tried setting the max-height to 50% for the top container scrollable area.
It didn't show 50% as expected.

Is there a way to achieve this without using flex-box, as I need to support older IE versions.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 30%;
  display: table;
}

.top {
  padding: 24px;
  background: yellow;
  display: table-row;
}

.top div {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 50%;
}

.bottom {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 24px;
  background: tomato;
  display: table-row;
}

.bottom div {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are setting your max-height to 100px

Comment: @andrepaulo, I set the max-height to a fixed number in order to achieve auto scroll for the two top and bottom containers. Setting it to 50% didn't work.

Comment: take a look ... http://jsfiddle.net/wq4p51ae/1/ is that what you need?

Comment: @andrepaulo, thanks for your response. Not quite, the top container needs to have height from 0 to 50% depending how much content it contains (dynamic).

Comment: you want to balance the size of top and bottom's div... not letting them go over 50%?

Comment: @andrepaulo, I edited the question. See if it's more clear. I want to only cap the top div to 50% max. The bottom div can have any height.

Comment: see, if this is what you're looking for... http://jsfiddle.net/wq4p51ae/2/

Comment: @andrepaulo, the bottom div is now not scrollable..

Comment: You can apply the same concept.. I'm not at the desk now.. but if you cannot do and nobody helps you.. I'll try helping you

Comment: @andrepaulo, I cannot apply max-height to the bottom div and that depends on the top div's height, if that's the concept you are referring to. I don't have any help nearby. Thanks for offering your help.

Comment: @jf1034 Wanted to mention that this has nothing to do with angular2

Comment: @DavidLee, thanks, I wasn't sure because I have seen some issues with scrolling in Angular2. I removed "Angular 2" from the question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.top {
  padding: 24px;
  background: #000000;
  height: 300px;
  width:40%;
  float:left;
  overflow: auto;
  color:#ffffff;
}

.bottom {
  height: 300px;
  padding: 24px;
  background: #ff0000;
  color:#ffffff;
  display: table-row;
  width:40%;
  float:left;
}

li{list-style:none;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">
    <div>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
      <li>DYNAMIC CONTENT</li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have built up on @andrepaulo's fiddle.

Cheers

Comment: I am seeing two containers horizontally but not vertically in the snippet you provided.